# How do i resolve Flask Sqalchemy Integrity error?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Hi guys i am facing an integrity error when i try to do relationship between parent(User) and child(Transactions). Will appreciate an advice on how to solve thanks!

Error:
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) NOT NULL constraint failed:
transaction.user_id
[SQL: INSERT INTO "transaction" (title, type, date, value, user_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]
[parameters: ('grocery', 'Expense', '2021-03-05 10:18:13.634757', 50, None)]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/gkpj)

```
routes.py: 
@app.route('/dashboard', methods = ('GET', 'POST'))
@login_required
def dashboard():
    form = TrackerForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        transaction = Transaction( title = form.transaction_name.data, value = form.value.data, type = form.type.data)
        db.session.add(transaction)
        db.session.commit()
        flash(f'Transaction has been recorded', 'success')
    else:
        print('form fail')
    return render_template('dashboard.html', form = form)

models.py:
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    image_file = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default='default.jpg')
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    transactions = db.relationship('Transaction', backref='user', lazy=True)

class Transaction(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'transaction'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    type = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable = False, default = datetime.utcnow)
    value = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable = False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
```

Comment: are you trying to add user_id = None on a one to many relationship? the transaction object you are trying to commit to db has no user_id.

Comment: Hi yes i am trying to do a one to many relationship, so that when a transaction is made it records who the user is. How should i do it instead? Thanks!

Comment: You can solve this by adding a user id to your transaction object: transaction = Transaction( title = form.transaction_name.data, value = form.value.data, type = form.type.data, user_id = current_user.id) would work if there is a current user object.